# Drupal 7 Views: Replace the auto-complete filter results by a view

Tags: autocomplete, filter, drupal-7, view

I have a view page which I use to search for users. This view has an exposed filter for the username which is an auto-complete field. The standard behavior is that the Usernames appear below the field.
What I want is to customize the appearance of this suggestions, add a photo for example. 
Is it possible to replace this standard suggestions by the results of a view?

Example: Facebook user search field